# restrict one port to a subnet but allow all others

Tags: linux, firewall, firewalld

I'm using Firewalld.  In general I'd like to leave the computer open for the other services I use, but I've one web server that I'd like to restrict to a subnet.

I can find plenty on opening one port and keeping the rest restricted but not the converse.

I'm using CentOS 7 but doubt that matters much.  Currently the firewall is off.  I think this command is something like what I want but I'm not sure if everything else will be restricted?

The machine is heavily used so I'm reluctant to start playing around"

```
% firewall-cmd  --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source not address="172.16.128.0/24" \
   port protocol="tcp" port="8880" drop'
```